# How would you guys do this mapping in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, hashmap

Let's say I have an array as follows:

```
[100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2]
```

And I want to create a map, like so:

```
{
 
   { key: 100,
     value: 2
   },
   { key: 100,
     value: 3
   }
   { key: 100,
     value: 4
   },

   { key: 200,
     value: 35
   },
   { key: 200,
     value: 42
   },

   { key: 300,
     value: 4
   },
   { key: 300,
     value: 4
   },
   { key: 300,
     value: 4
   },
   { key: 300,
     value: 6
   },
   { key: 300,
     value: 7
   },

   { key: 400,
     value: 2
   },

   
}
```

All the values in the bigger array are objects which have one or more fields.

I simulated the values with only one field using numbers 100, 200, 300, 400. You can call them flags. The rest of them being values with more than 1 field, of course.

My goal is to create map elements using the current flag with the items that follow it. For flag 300, the following elements are 4,4,4,6,7.

Here is what I tried:

```
let flagAndFollowingValues = new Map();
            let j=0;
            let followingElementsArray = [];
            console.log(itemsToBeCheckedArray[j]);
            for(let i=0; i<bigArray.length; i++){
                if(Object.keys(bigArray[i]).length > 1)
                {
                    followingElementsArray.push(bigArray[i]);
                }else if(Object.keys(bigArray[i]).length === 1){
                    if(i===0){
                        j++;
                        flagAndFollowingValues.set(itemsToBeCheckedArray[j], followingElementsArray);
                        followingElementsArray=[];
                    }else{
                        flagAndFollowingValues.set(itemsToBeCheckedArray[j], followingElementsArray);
                        followingElementsArray=[];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: `{ {key:value, key: value },{...}} ` is invalid. Did you mean an array of objects instead? `[{},{},...]`

Comment: @ChrisG, I mistyped

Comment: Please show us your attempts

Comment: What happens if you want a `value` greater than 100.

Comment: I edited the post with what I tried instead of trying to reply in the comments

Comment: @Keith, I used 100,200,300,400 to simulate objects that have only one field, call them flags. They are irrelevant, I made them this big to make them stand out from the values following each of them

Comment: I guess what you are trying to achieve can create another problem in the future.
Your flags and values are both numbers.

Comment: @RK_oo7  Yeah, it was kind of what I was commenting on, but apparently it's irrelevant.   A structure like -> `["100",2,3,4,"200",35,42,"300",4,4,4,6,7,"400",2]` might not be too bad..

Comment: DSA stands for Digital Signature Algorithm. Please don't add irrelevant tags. If in doubt, read tag description before you add it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the code is self-explanatory. Just iterate the array and either get a new key or add a value to the current key.

```js
const source = [100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2];

const mapped = [];
let key;
for(const value of source){
  if(value % 100 === 0){
     key = value;
     continue;
  }
  mapped.push({key,value});
}

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon. Take the time to explain what you've done and how it addresses the OP's question. (The code is never self-explanatory, especially if the OP is a beginner or having trouble with the logic of the problem to begin with)

Answer (score 3):

Another [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) option using a single flag instead of if/else/map's

---

1. If the current value if larger then `100`, set `flag` to that value
2. Otherwise, add a new object to the array, with `flag` as `key` and the current value as the `value`.

```js
const data = [100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2];
let flag = null;

const result = data.reduce((p, c, i) => {
    if (c >= 100) {
        flag = c;
    } else {
        p.push({ key: flag, value: c });         
    }
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the data by adding new groups to the end of the resulting array.

1. Reduce the data

   1. If the value is a key, add it to the end of the accumulator
   2. Else, push the current value to the last group in the accumulator
2. Flat-map each group of values into a sub-array of values (with their key)

```js
const
  input = [100, 2, 3, 4, 200, 35, 42, 300, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 400, 2],
  processData = (arr, keyPredicate) => arr
    .reduce((acc, n) => {
      if (keyPredicate(n)) acc.push({ key: n, values: [] });
      else acc[acc.length - 1].values.push(n);
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .flatMap(({ key, values }) => values.map(value => ({ key, value }))),
  processed = processData(input, n => n >= 100);

console.log(processed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Array#reduce() and Array#reduceRight() usually result in hard-to-read and less performant code. In almost every case, it can be replaced by .map, .filter, or a for-of loop.
-
from eslint recommended rules...

Comment: Did you write an answer to OP's question or write code to fly to the moon?

Comment: @silentmantra you do not need to acknowledge everything that an opinionated code style guide mentions. There is nothing wrong with using reduce.

Comment: @silentmantra   Note the term `usually`,  and the term `reduce` really fits the question, he is reducing the array.

Comment: @Wimanicesir that's what I thought as well, ahaha - but clearly he's smart, that's definetely an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

First create a map logic, then filter out false entries:

```js
// Declare what your current key is, so we can save it when needed
let currentKey = 0;

// We just want to return the key and value
// But not if the number is divisable by 100
let result = [100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2].map(
number => {

  // Check if key or value
  if (number % 100 === 0){
    currentKey = number
    return false;
  }
  
  return {key: currentKey, value: number}

}
);

// Remove false keys
result = result.filter(entry => entry !== false)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You filter out `0` which isn't in the description

Comment: Ok fixed it. Thanks for noting

Comment: Few!!!  You know when you quickly read something, your comment in my head had an extra `h`, and as such had totally different meaning.  Just shows, you always need to be careful when reading comments.. :)

Comment: Don't use a `map()` if you don't want an array of the same length returned, use `reduce()`

Comment: @pilchard seems you don't use eslint which has in the recommended rules:
Array#reduce() and Array#reduceRight() usually result in hard-to-read and less performant code. In almost every case, it can be replaced by .map, .filter, or a for-of loop.

Comment: @silentmantra I wouldn't use a reduce myself, but if the answerer wants to use built-in methods then reduce is more appropriate than map.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed structure is useless, what you probably want is a map like

```
100 => [ 2, 3, 4 ]
200 => [ 35, 42 ]
```

etc

```js
let a = [100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2]

let m = new Map()
let key = null

for (let x of a)
    if (x % 100 === 0)
        key = x
    else if (m.has(key))
        m.get(key).push(x)
    else
        m.set(key, [x])

console.log([...m])
```

Comment: Suggesting an alternative structure is perfectly reasonable.  Telling the OP that the requested structure is useless is just insulting.  There may be perfectly good reasons for that structure... although I like yours better.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: if you find my wording inappropriate, feel free to file a complaint with the mods. I'm not interested in your lectures, thanks.

Comment: Just some friendly advice.  Feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If your flag is a multiple of 100, in that case it will work

```js
let flagObj = {};
const data = [100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2];
const res = data.reduce((acc, val, index)=> {
    let flag = val % 100;
    if(flag === 0 ){
        flagObj[val] = val;
    } else{
    let allFlags = Object.keys(flagObj);
    if(allFlags[allFlags.length-1]){
        let key = allFlags[allFlags.length -1]
        acc.push({
            key,
            value: val,
        });
    }
    }
    return acc;
},[]);
console.log('result>>>>>', res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we had a `splitWhenever` function that split an array into subarrays of consecutive values based on the result of a predicate, we could write this simply as

```js
const process = (xs) => 
  splitWhenever (n => n % 100 == 0) (xs) 
    .flatMap (([key, ...vals]) => vals .map (value => ({key, value})))
```

Such a `splitWhenever` is fairly generic and useful in other situations, and it might go in our personal toolkit to be reused as necessary.  We might use it like this:

```js
const isOdd = (n => n % 2 === 1)
splitWhenever (isOdd) ([5, 6, 8, 12, 3, 8, 10, 17, 24, 5, 7, 14, 28])
    //=> [[5, 6, 8, 12], [3, 8, 10], [17, 24], [5], [7, 14, 28]]
```

Or we might extend it to allow the predicate to check the current value against the previous one, like this:

```js
const sameDecade = (x, y) => Math .floor (x / 10) !== Math .floor (y / 10) 
splitWhenever (sameDecade) ([23, 27, 22, 45, 42, 57, 51, 12, 16, 25, 27, 21])
    //=> [[23, 27, 22], [45, 42], [57, 51], [12, 16], [25, 27, 21]]
```

And of course such a function could be used like this:

```js
// const isFlag = (n) => n > 99)
// const isFlag = (n) => [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000] .includes (n)
const isFlag = (n) => n % 100 == 0
splitWhenever (isFlag) ([100, 2, 3, 4, 200, 35, 42, 300, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 400, 2])
    //=> [[100, 2, 3, 4], [200, 35, 42], [300, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7], [400, 2]]
```

(Note the various versions of `isFlag`.  The question doesn't make it clear how you determine the flag values.)

I have such a `splitWhenever` I used fairly often.  We can use it like this:

```js
const splitWhenever = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .length == 0 ? [] : xs .slice (1) .reduce (
    ((xss, x, i) => pred (x, xs[i]) 
       ? [...xss, [x]] 
       : [...xss .slice (0, -1), [... xss [xss .length - 1], x]]
    ), [[xs [0]]]
  )

const process = (xs) => 
  splitWhenever (n => n % 100 == 0) (xs) 
    .flatMap (([key, ...vals]) => vals .map (value => ({key, value})))

console .log (
  process ([100, 2, 3, 4, 200, 35, 42, 300, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 400, 2])
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#forEach` and `Array#push` methods as follows:

```js
const
      input = [100,2,3,4,200,35,42,300,4,4,4,6,7,400,2],
      
      output = [];
      
let      
      key = 0;
      
      input.forEach(value => {
          if( value < 100 ) {
              output.push({key, value});
          } else {
              key = value;
          }
      });
      
      
console.log( output );
```